# A neat way to prove that the set of symmetric polynomials with n variables is a subring of the ring of all polynomials with n variables

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

So I am tasked to prove that the set of symmetric polynomials with n (n>2, let's say) variables is a subring of the ring of all polynomials with n variables.

I know intuitively that if $A,B$ are such symmetric polymials then $A+B$, $AB$, and $-A$ are all closed respectively. Yet how do I word this proof neatly? Is there a good way to express symmetric polymials so I can do additions and multiplications and additive inverses without confusing the heck out of everyone? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A polynomial $f\in K[X_1,\dotsc,x_n]$ is symmetric iff
$$f(X_{\sigma(1)},\dotsc,X_{\sigma(n)})=f(X_1,\dotsc,X_n)$$
for all $\sigma\in S_n$.

So we have for example for symmetric $f$ and $g$ that
$$\begin{align}&(fg)(X_{\sigma(1)},\dotsc,X_{\sigma(n)})\\=&f(X_{\sigma(1)},\dotsc,X_{\sigma(n)})g(X_{\sigma(1)},\dotsc,X_{\sigma(n)})\\=&f(X_1,\dotsc,X_n)g(X_1,\dotsc,X_n)\\=&(fg)(X_1,\dotsc,X_n)\end{align}$$
and so $fg$ is also symmetric. Do the others in a similar way.

Comment: but is this "neat"?

Comment: @Jasper In my opinion, yes. Clear, straightforward, easy to remember, uses only the definitions... what else can one wish for? :)

Answer (score 6):

For every fixed permutation of the $n$ variables, there is a corresponding ring automorphism of the ring of polynomials in those variables (just replace the variables by their image under the permutation, systematically wherever they occur in a polynomial). The set of fixed points of *any* automorphism$\sigma$ of a ring is clearly a subring (if $\sigma(x)=x$ and $\sigma(y)=y$ then clearly $\sigma(x+y)=x+y$ and $\sigma(xy)=xy$, and so forth). Finally the set of symmetric polynomials is just the intersection of these subrings taken over all permutations of the variables (or just over the adjacent transpositions is you want to be economical); the intersection of any collection of subrings is a subring.

Comment: You are absolutely right to look at it this way since it ties everything back to the basic point of view in abstract algebra. Yet since @sigmabe 's answer suits my particular question better, I would have to accept his answer. Have a good day.